# How to access a resource from a java library packed into its own .jar

Tags: java, file, maven, jar

I have a library project with some resources that I would like to load and use.
I would be using this library in another project so I have to pack the resources into the .jar. This is how that's achieved:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

The problem comes when trying to retrieve the file, I do:

```
String resourceName = "myTemplateResource.json";
URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName);
```

url is assigned a `null` value. It happens in the library's tests and in the dependant project. Any hint of what is missing?

Also tested using

```
MyClass.class.getResource("/myTemplateResourceName.json");
```

and

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("src/main/resources/myTemplateResource.json");
```

with the same result.

Comment: Also tested that with the same result

Comment: `It happens in the library's tests` - you mean that project itself can't find it's own resources? Are you sure you placed that file in `src/main/resources` with that exact name? It works for me (the second way) and I have no idea why it wouldn't (with the `resources` element in pom and without it, it's not necessary here)

Comment: Instead of guessing, examine your .jar file.  You can do this in the Files view of any IDE, or you can use the [jar command line tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html), or you can copy the .jar file to a new file, change its extension to .zip, and use any zip tool (since a .jar file is actually just a zip file with a special manifest entry).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was something wrong with the filename that I was not able to find out. Renamed the file and now it's fine.

To answer my question:

First add the resource to the jar on the .pom file.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Then access your file.

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName);
```

From there you can get an `InputStream`. As simple as it looks.

Answer (score 8):

Use `getResourceAsStream()` method to load the resource from the .jar file as follows:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(locaiton);
```

e.g.: If the file 'myTemplateResourceName.json' is located directly in the resources folder, use only the file name. It is wrong if you add a slash (/) in front of the path.

```
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("myTemplateResourceName.json");
```

Note: You have to place the resource file in the `main/resources` (don't keep it in the `test/resources` section since that is not packed in the jar file) folder in the project which is being used to create the jar file.